# text of md-autocomplete with md-float-label becomes invisible when leaving the input

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

Everything works very nice, but when you click outside the autocomplete input the text gets invisible, if you click in the input it goes black again and you see it is there.
Here is my html:

```
   <body ng-app='myapp' layout="column" ng-controller="autocompleteController as ctrl">
<md-content layout-align="center" layout="row">
<md-input-container style="background-color: #3C83E1; padding: 1vh 1vh 1vh 1vh" flex="33" class="md-whiteframe-4dp">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" style="margin-bottom: 1vh; margin-top: 1vh">
        <img src="http://www.simplesdental.com/assets/img/simplesdental-logo-b.svg">
    </div>
    <md-autocomplete
            md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
            md-autoselect="true"
            md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
            md-items="item in ctrl.queryProcurar(ctrl.searchText)"
            md-item-text="item.name"
            md-floating-label="Nome do Paciente"
    >
        <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.name}}</span>
        <md-not-found>
            N&atilde;o foi encontrado um paciente com o nome "{{ctrl.searchText}}".
        </md-not-found>
    </md-autocomplete>

</md-input-container>
```

and my js:

```
    angular.module('myapp', ['ngMaterial'])
        .controller("autocompleteController", function ($http) {
            Object.filter = function (obj, predicate) {
                var result = {}, key;
                for (key in obj) {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && !predicate(obj[key])) {
                        result[key] = obj[key];
                    }
                }
                return result;
            };
            this.queryProcurar = function (query) {
                return $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
                    .then(function (response) {
                        var res = response.data.filter(function (obj) {
                            return obj.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) != -1;
                        });
                        return res;
                    })
            }
        })
```

here, a demo: http://codepen.io/iurypiva/pen/YZQeBN

Answer (score 1):

Since I was using this in an `ng-repeat`, I didn't want to give the same id to multiple elements in order to style it, so I looked further.

The problem actually turns out that the `input` portion of the `md-autocomplete` is wrapped in its own `md-input-container`.  The css in question checks to see if there is an input inside an `md-input-container` that does **not** have the `md-input-has-value` class.  The outside one (yours and mine) does not, just the inside one.

So I had choices.

I could remove the md-input-container and make it a div, as suggested in another answer.  However, because I have a few other inputs inside `md-input-container`s already in my page, and because the `md-autocomplete` would not be inside the `md-input-container` (just the `input` inside it), I'd have to duplicate all the styling that md-input-container uses (text-align: vertical; padding: 2px; etc.).

Or I could add `class="md-input-has-value"` to my `md-input-container`.

I went the simpler route.

```
<md-input-container class="md-input-has-value">
    <md-autocomplete ...
```

See [modified your codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgLdgw)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that md-input-container and md-floating-label has some weird conflicts in their css. Solved it changing de md-container to a simple div

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually just a CSS/styling issue

The easiest way to address this would be to use angular material's `md-input-id` attribute that is available for `md-autocomplete` ([documentation here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete))

```
<md-autocomplete
   md-input-id="searchinput"
   md-autoselect="true"
   md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
   md-items="item in ctrl.queryProcurar(ctrl.searchText)"
   md-item-text="item.name"
   md-floating-label="Nome do Paciente">
```

this attaches an ID (in my example I just called it `searchinput`) to the input that gets auto-generated by `md-autocomplete` that you can use to style the input.

The CSS that I tried in your codepen was then simply:

```
#searchinput { color: white; }
```

[here is a fork of your codepen with these updates](http://codepen.io/sweather131/pen/dvRqPK)